# TransformerException:An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x4)

Tags: java, jms, message-queue

I get this error message in my XML data.
When my Queue listener process this message, I am getting the below error message:

> -javax.xml.transform.TransformerException:  com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException:
>   An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x4) was found in the element content of the document.
>       [sample msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3G7mB.jpg)

when this message was processed by my queue listener, the error occurs.
Any possible solution to escape this message or to correct the data quality will be helpful.

[image: This is the code]

Comment: looks like a bug in your incoming data. XML should only contain ascii readable characters. So a number must be transported for example as it decimal ascii string - e.g. <number>123.456</number>. If you really want to transport binary data over XML, consider base64 encoding. See also here: https://web.archive.org/web/20140228010526/http://validchar.com/d/xml10/xml10_namestart

Comment: Yes the incoming data has the invalid character.  any suggestion to escape this character from the Queue to MDB listener?

Comment: Well, you could try &#60;  to encode hex 60. So SOH, for example is hex 01, try &#01; instead of SOH

Comment: Still I replaced those special character in the entry point. am setting the below error"
'com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.'"

Comment: you should post your complete xml document. Above, for example is missing the root element. Maybe read a bit more about XML ? What is this number supposed to be ?

Comment: <Order><employee id="EMP0001"><first_name>John</first_name><last_name>Doe</last_name><age>26</age><item>A23465</item><quantity>2</quantity><description>Made to move, the MQD32LLA/A Apple MacBook Air runs like a dream and feels light as a cloud. Sleek, stunning, and weighing in at under three pounds, the crisp 13.3" diagonal LED-backlit display serves as a worthy canvas for your projects, with dual-band Wi-Fi, 8GB of RAM, and a 128GB solid-state drive helping to carry the load</description><mobile>9 ú   ]</mobile><itemcode>À À</itemcode></employee></Order>

Comment: The above is the xml element sent form the front end

Comment: the text looks bit different as in image